# Using Interface Builder for a Switch

Tags: ios, xcode, save, switch-statement

If one uses interface builder to drag a Switch to a xib-file, the state can be set to on/off in IB. Is there a way to save the state of the switch until next time the app starts so that the switch is in the same state previous to being closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may save it using [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

first connect your switch as an IBOutlet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;
```

Also connect your switch as an IBAction, event type "Value Changed"

```
- (IBAction)switched:(id)sender;
```

then in your UIViewController's `viewDidLoad`

```
BOOL savedState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"mySwitch"];
[self.mySwitch setOn:savedState];
```

and in the new `switched:` action

```
- (IBAction)switched:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == self.mySwitch)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:self.mySwitch.isOn forKey:@"mySwitch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly. But I had to change (weak, nonatomic) to (nonatomic, retain)

Comment: oh, sorry about that. I don't know you are not using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this purpose.

Save the switch state like:

```
BOOL yourSwitchState = yourSwitch.on;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:yourSwitchState forKey:@"Switch"];
```

In the `viewWillAppear` get the value from user default and set it to switch like:

```
BOOL switchState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Switch"];
yourSwitch.on = switchState;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

- (void)handleSwitch:(UISwitch *)switch

{

if (switch.on)

{

```
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SwitchState"];
```

}

else

{
//

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"SwitchState"];
```

}

}

Next time when you app start

switch.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchState"];